# download properties file from Git and load before execution of any task in gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am having test.properties file which is common for 3 repository. Hence I checkin code in git. Lets say I have testA, testB and testC as three repo.
Now I want testA should first download test.properties, load it. then all task should refer to the property values.
How can I do this in gradle?

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about just downloading it into a `Properties` object then using properties from that to populate `test { systemProperties['myProp'] }`

Pseudocode might look something like this:

```
tasks.create('downloadTestProperties') {
    def props = new Properties()
    doFirst {
        def stream = "http://myurl/test.properties".toURL().openStream()
        props.load(stream)
        stream.close()
        outputs.properties.put('myTestProps', props)
    }
}

tasks.withType(Test) { testTask ->
    def downloadTask = tasks.findByName('downloadTestProperties')
    testTask.dependsOn downloadTask
    Properties testProps = downloadTask.outputs.properties.get('myTestProps') as Properties
    testProps.each {
        testTask.systemProperties[("$it.key")] = (it.value)
    }
}
```